# Looping through a data array and giving a from control name to an input field does not work correctly?

Tags: angular

**Problem:**

I am rendering input sets through a loop in angular. So in there I am setting form control name to the input field like this.

```
<input  formControlName="{{data.attributeName}}  min="1" id="{{data.id}}" type="{{data.type}}" />
```

But when I see the source in the inspect window it is not showing the form control name with the input field. Can someone help me to find out a way to solve this issue? Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do:

```
<input [formControlName]="data.attributeName" min="1" [id]="data.id" [type]="data.type" />
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<input [formControlName]="data.attributeName"  [id]="data.id"   [type]="data.type">
```

You have to use property binding.